# Maximum volume of rectangular prism with known surface area

Tags: calculus

I have a sheet of cardboard 64cm x 51cm. I need to make a cereal box that is a rectangular prism out of the cardboard. However I must use as much of the cardboard as possible to minimise waste. The prism needs to be constructed from one piece of board. It needs to maximize the volume of the box/prism. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If we cut equal-sized square notches of side length $x$ from the corners of the sheet, then the volume of a rectangular prism from the sheet would be

$$V(x) = x (a-2 x) (b-2 x) = 4 x^3 - 2 (a+b) x^2 + a b x$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the sides of the sheet.  We maximize by solving $V'(x)=0$:

$$V'(x) = 12 x^2-4 (a+b) x+a b=0 \implies x_{\pm} = \frac{a+b}{6} \pm \frac16 \sqrt{a^2-a b+b^2}$$

For a max, $V''(x) \lt 0$, so that the volume is a maximum when $x=x_-$.  In your case, $a=64$ cm and $b=51$ cm, so that each square notch is about $9.40$ cm on a side.

It is possible to maximize further by cutting rectangular notches, but I hope this illustrates how to go about it.